# Setting up a 2 DMZ configuration, simulating an attacker in the middle zone, pinging hosts after the second firewall is not possible

Tags: networking, security, firewall, dmz

I am setting up a network with a 2 DMZ configuration and decided to put an attacker within the middle zone of both firewalls. I am trying to ping some of the hosts that are located after the second firewall but I am not being able to do it (no answer). Is there any rule anyone can think of that would let me do that? The interface that connects to the middle zone currently allows any type of IPv4 traffic to facilitate testing and implementation.

The layout of the Network:
[Network layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBt8r.png)

The attacker would be in the WORKERS network (the internal attacker, I also included an external attacker that is between the router that connects to the Internet and the first firewall).

Comment: Can you draw the layout of the network that you currently have set up?

Comment: @user1686 you should be able to see it now